# Scala match error

Tags: scala

I tried to replace my isInstanceOf check with a match, but it does not work.

In my method I do a check for a tree node - if it is a leaf - I want to return it inside a Vector right away, if not - I continue with the method.

So originally I had:

```
    //code here
    if (common.isInstanceOf[LeafNode]) {
        return Vector(common.asInstanceOf[LeafNode].data)
    }
    //code here
```

then I tried to replace it with:

```
    //code here
     common match {
        case leaf: LeafNode => return Vector(leaf.data)
    }
    //code here
```

but I get scala.MatchError.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're getting a `MatchError` in the case where your `common` is not a `LeafNode`. Your `if` and `match` expressions are not equivalent. I think the most direct way to make them equivalent is:

```
common match {
  case leaf: LeafNode => return Vector(leaf.data)
  case _ =>
}
```

But I'd recommend looking at the whole code block and working out are more functional way to do this job. That is, without the `return` in the middle. Remember that match is an expression, so that something like this may be possible:

```
def foo = {
  //code here
  common match {
    case leaf: LeafNode => Vector(leaf.data)
    case notLeaf: Branch => //code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you use return?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the set of cases in your `match` block is not exhaustive; if `common` is anything but a `LeafNode`, a `MatchError` will be thrown. You can solve this by having a catch-all case like so:

```
common match {
  case leaf: LeafNode => return Vector(leaf.data)
  ... // other cases
  case other => ... // what to do if nothing else matches
}
```

This is analogous to the `default` case in a Java switch statement. The `other` case is called an "irrefutable pattern" because it has no characteristics; it doesn't require a particular type or constructor, so it will always match anything that falls through to it. The name of the variable doesn't have to be `other`, it can be anything you want, or even `_` ... in fact you don't need to bind a new variable here since it will be identical to `common`.

On a point of style, it's generally bad form to put return statements inside of a `match` block; the entire block is an expression which evaluates to one of its cases, so just return the entire expression. Also, you don't need to use the `return` keyword at all, as the last expression in a function definition will be used as the result.

Comment: in fact, if you do have a return statement in your function, the scala 2.9 compiler forces you to explicitly state the return type of the function. Not sure about earlier versions though